# Должно ли быть тире после "мы"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Все мы часть чего-то большого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом предложении ***мы*** — подлежащее, ***часть*** — сказуемое.

[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92)

> 8. Если подлежащее выражено **личным местоимением**, а сказуемое — формой именительного падежа существительного, тире между ними **обычно не ставится**: *Я честный человек и никогда не говорю комплиментов*.
>
> Однако тире в этом случае ставится:
>
> 1) при **логическом подчеркивании**: *Я — страница твоему перу. Всё приму. Я белая страница. Я — хранитель твоему добру*... (Цв.)

Таким образом, возможны оба варианта:

*Все мы часть чего-то большого.* — произносится без паузы, ударение падает на ***часть***.
*Все мы — часть чего-то большого.* — ударение на ***все*** или на ***мы***, выражена пауза.

Comment: я хотел написать только про тире в названии вопроса